# Question about algebraic elements and minimal polynomial

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I am struggling with a problem of Galois Theory. It says the following:

Let $L$ be a field, $G$ a finite subgroup of the automorphisms group of $L$ and let $K = L^G$
the field of fixed points of $G$. Prove that every element $a$ in $L\setminus K$ is algebraic over
$K$ and the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$ is $(x - a_1)(x - a_2) \dotsm(x - a_r)$, where
$a_1,\dots, a_r$ are distinct, $r = |G|$ and $\{a_1,\dots, a_r\} = \{g(a) : \text{ for all $g$ in $G$}\}$.

Any help would be fine for me in order to finish this exercise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to prove that the extension is finite, if $a\in L$, the coefficients of $P_a(X)=\Pi_{g\in G}(X-g(a))$ are in $K$, since for every $h\in G$, $P^h_a(X)=\Pi_{g\in G}(X-hg(a))=P_a(X)$.